# Image.load event is not triggered in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onload

I am trying to run some code when an image is loaded on Canvas with this code:

```js
var img = document.getElementById("image");
var width = 400;

function handleFiles() {
  var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('input').files;
  var file = filesToUpload[0];

  // Create a file reader
  var reader = new FileReader();
  // Set the image once loaded into file reader
  reader.onload = function(e) {
    img.onload = function() {
      if (this.naturalWidth > width) {
        this.width = width;
      }
      console.log('loaded')
    }
    img.src = e.target.result;
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

```html
<img src="" id="image">
<input id="input" type="file" onchange="handleFiles()">
```

The code works perfectly when I open the page on Windows, Mac, and Android with any browser.
But There are some problem with iPhone I tried Safari and Chrome but none of them work in iPhone. What I can do to make it work when open from iPhone?
Here is an example usage of this that I found and it does not work when opened in iPhone either:

http://techslides.com/demos/image-video/create.html

Comment: I would suggest moving `img.onload` out of `handleFiles` altogether. There doesn't seem to be a reason to reattach the event handler every time the user changes the file and the file is read. The event handler code stays the same no matter what; it's just the `src` that changes. I don't know if that will fix the iPhone issue though, but it can't hurt.

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Are you sure you're trying to load a valid image? Didn't you get an `error` event?